# Orbit Collision Angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a game, and I currently have objects continuously orbiting around a sphere at a fixed distance. I need to allow the object to bounce off of each other. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

I have the collision detection working, and each object has a bounding sphere. I am able to get the point of collision, I just need to take the current rotation vector from each object and get the resulting "bounce" angle (vector to rotate around) and have each object continue orbiting around it's new vector.

Let me know if that doesn't make sense or if you need anything else! I should mention that this is done using Unity3D (I am not using rigidbodies, or the built in physics engine for performance reasons)

**Edit:**

Here is what I've tried:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    // Determine resultant rotation axis
    Vector3 collisionNormal = collider.ClosestPointOnBounds(thisTransform.position);
    rotationAxis = Vector3.Reflect(rotationAxis, collisionNormal);
}
```

Here is a link to the Vector3.Reflect() method in the Unity3D docs: [Vector3.Reflect()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html)

At this point the objects don't start moving in a new direction they collide and then don't bounce off. They just appear to stop when the collision occurs.

Comment: Why dont you take the current rotation vector from each object and get the resulting "bounce" angle and have each object continue orbiting around it's new vector? Code demonstrating what you've tried and what doesn't work and what you expect vs actual would help!

Comment: That is exactly what I need to do, I just don't know how to go about figuring that out. I've tried the Unity3D `Reflect()` method on the `Vector3` class but that may be incorrect. See my edits.

Comment: gamedev.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question.

Comment: I'm not sure about the sticking thing but is there a reason you're calling the ClosestPointOnBounds the normal?  That function returns the closest position, not normal, on the bounding **box**.